# Extract tar.gz to STDOUT and zip STDOUT

Tags: tar, curl, zip, pipe

I need to extract an `tar.gz` archive I downloaded with `curl` into STDOUT and use the STDOUT as STDIN for zipping the files again.

```
curl -L someURL | tar xz --strip-components=1 -O| zip -r test.zip
```

gives me `enter cocurl: (23) Failed writing bodyde here`.

The problem is produced by the `-O` flag of tar.

Answer (score 3):

Your're missing a minus sign before the -O and missed the minus argument for zip:

`curl -L someURL | tar xzf - -O | zip test.zip -` works on my system with

- curl 7.26.0
- tar (GNU tar) 1.26
- Zip 3.0

Comment: okay this seems to work better, but the zip command does not get the input from STDOUT

Comment: no not working, tar says `-` not found in the archive

Comment: @Flatron have you tried a copy and paste of what @Jan suggested? The venerable `tar` hasn't changed its argument syntax in decades.

Comment: I did a copy and paste and the command itself is working, but the zip is only containing a file `-` that is a zip of the whole stdout output binary. So not really useful.

Comment: You might be doing something else or have a different version of tar, curl or zip - on the machines I have access to, the zip is a normal zip archive with the compressed files inside.